# Google Invisible reCAPTCHA breaks Firefox JavaScript

Tags: javascript, firefox, google-api, recaptcha

I have tried pretty much every which way to configure the Google Invisible reCAPTCHA widget, but there is always an issue with the latest Firefox browser, detailed as follows:

- add the plugin to a web page, which has other JS such as a dropdown menu
- load the web page
- keep loading the web page over and over, in an attempt to catch it 'half loaded'
- eventually you will see for a split second an alert "The page at https://www.google.com says: Cannot contact reCAPTCHA. Check your connection and try again"
- from now on, JavaScript is entirely broken until you restart the Firefox window

[image: Alert of Google reCAPTCHA failing]

This never happens in Chrome, and appears to be Firefox only. I am surprised to not find any reports of this major issue with vendors Google and Firefox (unsure which party is to blame), so created this ticket.

This issue can be replicated on the [official Google Invisible reCAPTCHA Demo](https://www.google.com/recaptcha/api2/demo?invisible=true) by quickly reloading the page. This will eventually show the alert and break the entire demo, making all form inputs unresponsive until the Firefox window is closed and re-opened.

At the time of writing, I am using OSX Firefox 57.0.1 (64-bit) to replicate this issue, but has also been replicated on the same Firefox under Windows 10.

Update after valid comment from Federico, as this is being reported a lot but no solutions or workarounds that I can find: [Google Groups Search](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!searchin/recaptcha/%22Cannot$20contact$20reCAPTCHA.$20Check$20your$20connection$20and$20try$20again%22%7Csort:date)

Is this a known issue and are there any plans to resolve from either Firefox or Google, or more importantly has anybody managed to put a workaround in place in the meantime?

Comment: If you think this is a bug, you should report it to Mozilla or Google, not stackoverflow.

Comment: I appreciate your point @FedericoklezCulloca, but having checked the Google Discussion Groups this is a pretty heavily reported issue with no solutions, and since reCAPTCHA is such a heavily used feature I wondered if any of the smart brains at SO had a workaround solution.

Answer (score 0):

I think the issue is resolved now. Try again and it is giving successful verification. I guess it was a bug which they fixed. If the problem still persists please try upgrading Firefox to the latest version.

[image: Successful Verification at the mentioned site]

Comment: Thanks for checking but sorry no it's not resolved. If you simply go to the form and hit submit, it will work fine. But if you refresh the page quickly until you see the alert popup appear for a split second, subsequent form submits will not work.